# Complicated min/max multi-table query

Tags: sql

I need to get the min and max score of group ids, but only if they are enabled:

```
cdu_group_sl:          cdu_group_cc:          cdu_group_ph:
--------------------   --------------------   --------------------
|id |name |enabled |   |id |name |enabled |   |id |name |enabled |
--------------------   --------------------   --------------------
|1  |sl_1 |1       |   |1  |cc_1 |1       |   |1  |ph_1 |0       |
|2  |sl_3 |1       |   |2  |cc_2 |0       |   |2  |ph_2 |1       |
|3  |sl_4 |1       |   |3  |cc_3 |1       |   |3  |ph_3 |1       |
--------------------   --------------------   --------------------
```

Scores are found in a separate table:

```
cdu_user_progress
----------------------------------
|id |group_type |group_id |score |
----------------------------------
|1  |sl         |1        |50    |
|1  |cc         |1        |10    |
|1  |ph         |1        |20    |
|1  |sl         |2        |80    |
|1  |sl         |3        |20    |
|1  |cc         |3        |30    |
|1  |sl         |1        |40    |
|1  |ph         |1        |50    |
|1  |cc         |1        |40    |
|1  |ph         |2        |90    |
----------------------------------
```

I need to get a max and min score for each type of group for only enabled groups (for each type):

```
---------------------------------------------
|group_type |group_id |min_score |max_score |
---------------------------------------------
|sl         |1        |40        |50        |
|sl         |2        |80        |80        |
|sl         |3        |20        |20        |
|cc         |1        |10        |40        |
|cc         |3        |30        |30        |
|ph         |1        |20        |50        |
|ph         |2        |90        |90        |
---------------------------------------------
```

Any idea what the query might be???  So far I have:

```
SELECT * FROM cdu_user_progress 
JOIN cdu_group_sl ON (cdu_group_sl.id = cdu_user_progress.group_id AND cdu_user_progress.group_type = 'sl') 
JOIN cdu_group_cc ON (cdu_group_cc.id = cdu_user_progress.group_id AND cdu_user_progress.group_type = 'cc') 
JOIN cdu_group_ph ON (cdu_group_ph.id = cdu_user_progress.group_id AND cdu_user_progress.group_type = 'ph')
WHERE cdu_user_progress.uid = $student->uid 
AND (cdu_user_progress.group_type = 'sl' AND cdu_group_sl.enabled = 1) 
AND (cdu_user_progress.group_type = 'cc' AND cdu_group_cc.enabled = 1) 
AND (cdu_user_progress.group_type = 'ph' AND cdu_group_ph.enabled = 1)
```

Probably completely wrong...

Answer (score 1):

what about using a union to pick the groups you are interested in - something like:

```
select group_type, group_id min(score) min_score, max(score) max_score
from (
  select id, 'sl' grp from cdu_group_sl where enabled  = 1 
  union all 
  select id, 'cc' from cdu_group_cc where enabled  = 1 
  union all
  select id, 'ph' from cdu_group_ph where enabled  = 1 
) grps join cdu_user_progress scr
on grps.id = scr.group_id and grps.grp = scr.group_type 
group by  scr.group_type, scr.group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting up this project, I would recommend refining your data structure. Based on what you showed, you could benefit from only one `cdu_groups` table with a reference to a new `cdu_group_types` table, and removing the `group_type` column from `cdu_user_progress`.

If this is an established project, where changing the structure would be too disruptive... then one of the other answers showing a query would be a better/easier fit.

Otherwise, you could simplify things with restructured tables and end up with a query like:

```
SELECT group_type, 
    group_id, 
    MIN(score) as min_score,
    MAX(score) as max_score
FROM cdu_user_progress c
INNER JOIN cdu_groups g
  ON c.group_id=g.id
INNER JOIN cdu_group_types t
  ON g.group_type_id=t.id
WHERE enabled=1
GROUP BY group_type, group_id
```

This is shown, with expected results, in **[this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b607/1)**. With this structure you can add new group types as you want (and also cut down on amount of tables and joins). Tables would be (simplified in this code below, no FKs or anything):

```
CREATE TABLE cdu_user_progress
(id INT, group_id INT, score INT)

CREATE TABLE cdu_group_types
(id INT, group_type VARCHAR(3))

CREATE TABLE cdu_groups
(id INT, group_type_id INT, name VARCHAR(10), enabled BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1)
```

Granted moving data to a new structure may be a pain or not reasonable... but wanted to throw this out there as a possibility or just something to chew on.

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably the fastest way to do this query.  To optimize this, you should have an index on `group_id, enabled` on each of the three "sl", "cc", and "ph" tables:

```
select cup.*
from cdu_user_progress cup
where (cup.group_type = 'sl' and
       exists (select 1
               from cdu_group_sl sl
               where sl.id = cup.group_id and
                     sl.enabled = 1
              )
      ) or
      (cup.group_type = 'cc' and
       exists (select 1
               from cdu_group_cc cc
               where cc.id = cup.group_id and
                     cc.enabled = 1
              )
      ) or
      (cup.group_type = 'ph' and
       exists (select 1
               from cdu_group_ph ph
               where ph.id = cup.group_id and
                     ph.enabled = 1
              )
      )
```

As a note, having three tables with the same structure is usually a sign of a poor database schema.  These three tables should probably be combined into a single table, which would make this query much easier to write.